# More complex shapes using nested for loops in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, shapes

I have seen some where they do simple examples of X or triangles or diamonds etc. I'd like to know how to make a complex shape like this:

```
#                 #
 ##             ##
  ###         ###
   ####     ####
    ###########
    ###########
   ####     ####
  ###         ###
 ##             ##
#                 #
```

I'm extremely new to programming, don't know the basic functions of the code itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int spaces = 4;
  int hashes = 1;
  for(int row=0;row<10;row++)
  {
      for(int spaces=0;spaces<4;spaces++)
      {
          cout<<" ";
      }
      for(int hashes=0;hashes<1;hashes++)
      {
          cout<<"#";
      }
      cout<<endl;

      if(row<5&&row>6)
      {
          spaces--;
          hashes+=2;
      }
      else
      {
          spaces++;
          hashes-=2;
      }

  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are two aspects to creating such shapes -- come up with a logic and encode that logic in a programming language. Which aspect are you having trouble with?

Comment: Like this: http://ideone.com/ePsJDZ. That is a comment to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990496/how-to-print-an-x-shape-in-c).

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's cheating :)

Comment: @juanchopanza mostly problem solving strategies, I don't have problems with syntax or anything, just the problem of how to approach the question in a logical manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use a "raytracing" approach; i.e.

```
for (int y=0; y<rows; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<cols; x++) {
        if (func(x, y)) {
            std::cout << "#";
        } else {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

for example with `rows = cols = 20` and `func` defined as

```
bool func(int x, int y) {
    return (x-10)*(x-10) + (y-10)*(y-10) < 8*8;
}
```

you would get a circle

Comment: Here's your circle bro, after fixing a critical new line bug http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1baa631494b4dfa0

Answer (score 0):

Many assignments to draw shapes like yours are based on symmetry, in both horizontal and vertical directions.  For example, in the horizontal direction, the characters from left to middle are mirrored after the center point.

The old fashioned method for drawing shapes is to store them in a 2 dimensional array, then print out the array:

```
unsigned char letter_E[7][5] =
{
  {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
  {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
  {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
};

for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 7; ++row)
{
  for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 5; ++column)
  {
    std::cout << letter_E[row][column];
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Also, search the internet for "ASCII art".